# Radon–Nikodym Derivative and Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> **Theorem 1.3.1. (Bayes' theorem):**
>   Suppose that $X$ has a parametric family $\mathcal{P}_0$ of distributions with parameter space $\Omega$.
>   Suppose that $P_\theta \ll \nu$ for all $\theta \in \Omega$, and let $f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid\theta)$ be the conditional density (with respect to $\nu$) of $X$ given $\Theta = \theta$.
>   Let $\mu_\Theta$ be the prior distribution of $\Theta$.
>   Let $\mu_{\Theta\mid X}(\cdot \mid x)$ denote the conditional distribution of $\Theta$ given $X = x$.
>   Then $\mu_{\Theta\mid X} \ll \mu_\Theta$, a.s. with respect to the marginal of $X$, and the Radon–Nikodym derivative is
>   $$
> \frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{\mathrm d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x)
> = \frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta(t)}
> $$
>   for those $x$ such that the denominator is neither $0$ nor infinite.
>   The prior predictive probability of the set of $x$ values such that the denominator is $0$ or infinite is $0$, hence the posterior can be defined arbitrarily for such $x$ values.

I tried to derive the right hand side of the Radon–Nikodym derivative above but I got different result, here is my attempt:

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{\mathrm d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x) &= f_{\Theta\mid X}(\theta\mid x) \mathrm \space \space \space[1]\\
&=\frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta) \cdot f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{f_X(x)}\\
&=\frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta) \cdot f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \cdot f_{\Theta}(t) \space \mathrm dt}\\
&=\frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta) \cdot f_{\Theta}(\theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta(t)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

but now, where does $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$ go?

for $[1]$ see slide $10$ of the following document: http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mlss09/mlss_slides/Orbanz_1.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{\mathrm d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x)
= \frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta(t)}
$$
Let's rearrange it a little bit:
$$
\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X} (\theta \mid x)
= \frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta(t)}
$$
and then:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{d\nu} (\theta \mid x)
= \frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta) \, (\mathrm d\mu_\Theta/d\nu)(\theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, \mathrm d\mu_\Theta(t)}
$$
$${}$$
$$
\frac{d\mu_{\Theta\,\mid\, X=x}}{d\nu}(\theta) = \frac{ \displaystyle \frac{d\mu_{X\,\mid\,\Theta=t}}{d\lambda}(x) \cdot \frac{d\mu_\Theta}{d\nu}(\theta) }{ \displaystyle \int \frac{d\mu_{X\,\mid\,\Theta=t} (x)}{d\lambda} \cdot d\mu_\Theta(t) }
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer @MichaelHardy (I'm going to accept it in a moment). I have two questions if you don't mind: $1)$ Is $f_{\Theta}(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta}}{\mathrm d\nu} (\theta)$ here? $2)$ if so how is $\frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{\mathrm d\nu} (\theta \mid x) = \frac{\mathrm d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{\mathrm d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BlgKhalil : It occurred to me to ponder that and I may have been hasty about detail, but the answer lies in applying the ideas seen here. To be continued shortly.....

Comment: The two expressions $d\mu_{\Theta\,\mid\,X=x}(\theta)$ and $d\mu_{\Theta\,\mid\,X=x} (\theta)/d\nu,$ are not the same.

Comment: $$\begin{align} \frac{d\mu_{\Theta\,\mid\,X=x}}{d\nu} (\theta) & = \frac{f_{X\,\mid\,\Theta=\theta}(x) \cdot \frac{d\mu_\Theta}{d\nu}(\theta)}{\Pr(X=x)} \\ {} \\ \end{align}$$

Comment: Here's a problem: With respect to which measure is $f_X$ the density?

Comment: $$
\frac{d\mu_{\Theta\,\mid\, X=x}}{d\nu}(\theta) = \frac{ \displaystyle \frac{d\mu_{X\,\mid\,\Theta=t}}{d\lambda} \cdot \frac{d\mu_\Theta}{d\nu}(\theta) }{ \displaystyle \int \frac{d\mu_{X\,\mid\,\Theta=t} (x)}{d\lambda} \cdot \frac{d\mu_\Theta}{d\nu} (t) }
$$

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelHardy, really appreciate the help. My sincere apologies for taking your time.

Comment: @BlgKhalil: You needn't apologize.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have always trouble when ppl work with infinitesimals like that, i.e., that they just multiply by them etc. Can you maybe give a short argument what is really going on in the first two lines. I.e. how the rigorous transformation would look like where you get the $d\mu$ on the other side and then divide by $d\nu$

Comment: also in the last comment with a formula, where does the t come from? More generally, what is going on behind the scenes, when going just from conditioning from X to X=x here?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about how to reconcile the familiar version of Bayes' theorem
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}
p(\theta \mid x) = \frac{p(\theta) p(x \mid \theta)}{p(x)}
$$
with the formal version presented [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/444082/97872):
$$
\tag{2}
\label{2}
\frac{d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}}{d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x)
= \frac{f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, d\mu_\Theta(t)}.
$$
(I will be using the same notation as at that link.)

On the one hand, the left-hand-side of \eqref{1} is supposed to represent a density of the conditional distribution of $\Theta$ given $X$ *with respect to some unspecified dominating measure on the parameter space*.

On the other hand, the left-hand-side of \eqref{2} is the density of the conditional distribution of $\Theta$ given $X$ *with respect to the prior distribution*.

If, in addition, the prior distribution $\mu_\Theta$ has a density $f_\Theta$ with respect to some (let's say $\sigma$-finite) measure $\lambda$ on the parameter space $\Omega$, then $\mu_{\Theta \mid X}(\cdot\mid x)$ is also absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ for $\mu_X$-a.e. $x \in \mathcal{X}$, and if $f_{\Theta \mid X}$ represents a version of the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $d\mu_{\Theta\mid X}/d\lambda$, then \eqref{2} yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{\Theta \mid X}(\theta \mid x)
&= \frac{d \mu_{\Theta \mid X}}{d\lambda}(\theta \mid x) \\
&= \frac{d \mu_{\Theta \mid X}}{d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x) \frac{d \mu_{\Theta}}{d\lambda}(\theta) \\
&= \frac{d \mu_{\Theta \mid X}}{d\mu_\Theta}(\theta \mid x) f_\Theta(\theta) \\
&= \frac{f_\Theta(\theta) f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, d\mu_\Theta(t)} \\
&= \frac{f_\Theta(\theta) f_{X\mid \Theta}(x\mid \theta)}{\int_\Omega f_\Theta(t) f_{X\mid\Theta}(x\mid t) \, d\lambda(t)}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hopefully this shows you how to get to the familiar form \eqref{1} from \eqref{2}.

Comment: How anyone can stomach what you call the "familiar" version I don't know. (But you see it all the time.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy I completely agree, it took me way too long to get used to seeing it everywhere in statistics/machine learning literature

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @ArtemMavrin, those two paragraphs clarified a lot, and I sincerely apologize for the repeated question. I've been studying probability theory in a superficial way as an undergrad now trying to study it solely in a measure theoretic way caused me a lot of confusion.

Comment: Hi @ArtemMavrin, I accepted Michael Hardy's answer because I promised him to accept it and it was also helpful, I hope you understand and I apologize again.

Comment: @BlgKhalil no need to apologize! best of luck on your journey to relearn probability!